# How can I write the winner's logic in a Tic Tac Toe game on Java?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

```
public void WinnerCheck() 
{
    if (m_allButtons[0][0].getText() == m_allButtons[0][1].getText() && m_allButtons[0][1].getText() == m_allButtons[0][2].getText()) 
    {
        DisableAllButtons();
    }
    else if (m_allButtons[1][0].getText() == m_allButtons[1][1].getText() && m_allButtons[1][1].getText() == m_allButtons[1][2].getText())
    {
        DisableAllButtons();
    }

}   

private void AddAllEventHandlers()
{
    if (m_allButtons != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                JButton currentButton = m_allButtons[i][j];
                currentButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                    {
                        ChangeButtonText(currentButton);
                        WinnerCheck();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the WinnerCheck() method whithin the ActionEvent, it actually disables all the buttons all together. I'm trying to write the the logic to where all the buttons are disabled once someone wins the tic tac toe game; by win I mean to have any row or column with the same  value (either X or O) but there aren't any player values or anything assigned. It just starts with X and alternates every click with the opposite value. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to compare strings, use `.equals` and not `==`. And an empty string is equivalent to another empty string, so when you are checking, you'll have to ensure that they are either "X" or "O", and not just an empty string.

Comment: "How can I write this?" is probably too broad of a question for SO, which is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a school assignment.

You need an algorithm for checking the win condition.  You don't need to check the whole board just the squares on possible win paths from the last play.

General algorithm:

1. Set total to 1.
2. If position (x-1)%3, (y-1)%3 is not the same token (X or Y), continue from step 6.
3. If position (x-1)%3, (y-1)%3 is the same token, add to total.
4. If position (x+1)%3, (y+1)%3 is not the same token, continue from step 6.
5. If position (x+1)%3, (y+1)%3 is the same token, add to total.  If total is 3, game won.
6. Repeat 1-5 for these coordinates ((x-1,y),(x+1,y)), ((x,y-1),(x,y+1)), and ((x-1,y+1),(x+1,y-1)) in place of ((x-1,y-1),(x+1,y+1)).